# NSDate compare to Parse Data not querying records as expected

Tags: swift, parsing, nsdate

I have a column "checkInTime" in my Parse class that is of type Date.

I am trying to query any checkInTimes after a certain time

Here is the code I am using

```
func reloadCheckInView() {

    checkIns.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    let friendsListQuery = PFQuery(className: "Friends")
    friendsListQuery.includeKey("friendId")
    friendsListQuery.includeKey("user")
    friendsListQuery.whereKey("friendId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    friendsListQuery.whereKey("approved", equalTo: true)

    friendsListQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                let user = object["user"] as! PFObject
                let now = NSDate()
                print(now)

                let BeforeNow = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(self.hourWindow * -3600)

                print(self.hourWindow)
                print(BeforeNow)

                let checkInQuery = PFQuery(className: "LocationCheckIn")
                checkInQuery.includeKey("user")
                checkInQuery.whereKey("CheckInTime", greaterThan: BeforeNow)
                checkInQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)

                //let subQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([friendsListQuery, checkInQuery])
                checkInQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        //print(results)
                        for result in results! {
                            self.checkIns.append(result)
                        }
                        print(self.checkIns)

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }

            }

        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

and my prints which shows the calculations are working as expected..in this case 1 hr before now.

```
2015-10-17 15:23:49 +0000
1.0
2015-10-17 14:23:49 +0000
[]
```

and no records found in my query.

If I comment out

```
checkInQuery.whereKey("CheckInTime", greaterThan: BeforeNow)
```

the record is printed and you can see the checkIn time should pass my query but doesn't. Any ideas?

```
[<LocationCheckIn: 0x12903edb0, objectId: M7zTD3qiCL, localId: (null)> {
   checkInPlaceId = "ChIJfc7vF8upVogRk20hK-LzaAM";
   checkInPlaceName = "12434 Willingdon Rd";
   checkInTime = "2015-10-17 14:26:00 +0000";
   location = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x127ed52f0, latitude: 35.436804, longitude: -80.828736>";
   user = "<PFUser: 0x127ed76d0, objectId: WCMmKTvNUC, localId: (null)>";
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

And as I just read through my own question I see my error.. a typo

```
checkInQuery.whereKey("CheckInTime", greaterThan: BeforeNow)
```

should be

```
checkInQuery.whereKey("checkInTime", greaterThan: BeforeNow)
```